# nvptx gcc (9.0.0/trunk) for openmp 4.5 off-loading to (gpu) device cannot find libgomp.spec

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda, openmp, offloading

I've been trying to install the OpenMP 4.5 off-loading to Nvidia GPU version of gcc for a while and so far no success, although I'm getting closer.

This time, I followed [this script](https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/04/building-gcc-with-support-for-nvidia.html), where I have made two changes: First I specified the trunk version of gcc instead of 7.2, secondly nvptx-newlib is now included in nvptx-tools according to the github repository, so I removed that part of the script. For easy reference, the original script is

```
    #!/bin/sh

#
# Build GCC with support for offloading to NVIDIA GPUs.
#

work_dir=$HOME/offload/wrk
install_dir=$HOME/offload/install

# Location of the installed CUDA toolkit
cuda=/usr/local/cuda

# Build assembler and linking tools
mkdir -p $work_dir
cd $work_dir
git clone https://github.com/MentorEmbedded/nvptx-tools
cd nvptx-tools
./configure \
    --with-cuda-driver-include=$cuda/include \
    --with-cuda-driver-lib=$cuda/lib64 \
    --prefix=$install_dir
make
make install
cd ..

# Set up the GCC source tree
git clone https://github.com/MentorEmbedded/nvptx-newlib
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/tags/gcc_7_2_0_release gcc
cd gcc
contrib/download_prerequisites
ln -s ../nvptx-newlib/newlib newlib
cd ..
target=$(gcc/config.guess)

# Build nvptx GCC
mkdir build-nvptx-gcc
cd build-nvptx-gcc
../gcc/configure \
    --target=nvptx-none --with-build-time-tools=$install_dir/nvptx-none/bin \
    --enable-as-accelerator-for=$target \
    --disable-sjlj-exceptions \
    --enable-newlib-io-long-long \
    --enable-languages="c,c++,fortran,lto" \
    --prefix=$install_dir
make -j4
make install
cd ..

# Build host GCC
mkdir build-host-gcc
cd  build-host-gcc
../gcc/configure \
    --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none \
    --with-cuda-driver-include=$cuda/include \
    --with-cuda-driver-lib=$cuda/lib64 \
    --disable-bootstrap \
    --disable-multilib \
    --enable-languages="c,c++,fortran,lto" \
    --prefix=$install_dir
make -j4
make install
cd ..
```

After quite a while, this successfully exits. Per the instructions on that webpage, I added $install_dir/lib64 to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH and additionally to LIBRARY_PATH.

Then as a test, I have the following basic test program

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   double data_array[1000000];

#pragma omp target teams distribute
   for (int idx = 0; idx < 1000000; ++idx)
   {
       data_array[idx] = idx;
   }   

   std::cout << "Hopefully this ran on the gpu...\n";
}
```

Then I try to compile this using `offload/install/bin/g++ -fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none main.cpp` then it returns with the following error message:

```
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
mkoffload: fatal error: offload/install/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: /home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0//accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The file libgomp.spec can be found in the aforementioned `$install_dir/lib64`, which on my system is `offload/install/lib64/`.

Some more information about my system:
Ubuntu 16.04, accessed through slurm
Cuda 9.0.176
4x Nvidia Tesla V100

offload/install/bin/g++ -v reports:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=offload/install/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc/configure --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --with-cuda-driver-include=/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/include --with-cuda-driver-lib=/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/lib64 --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/home/over_ng/offload/install
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.0.0 20180627 (experimental) (GCC)
```

offload/install/bin/g++ -print-search-dirs reports

```
install: /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/
programs: =/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/
libraries: =/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/lib64/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/lib64/../lib64/:/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/subversion-1.9.7-f5fbcx4xhwzrq5rhhco7byj7cbx2f4fs/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/subversion-1.9.7-f5fbcx4xhwzrq5rhhco7byj7cbx2f4fs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/subversion-1.9.7-f5fbcx4xhwzrq5rhhco7byj7cbx2f4fs/lib/../lib64/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib64/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib64/../lib64/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/../lib64/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../lib64/:/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/lib64/:/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/subversion-1.9.7-f5fbcx4xhwzrq5rhhco7byj7cbx2f4fs/lib/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib64/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

And finally, offload/install/bin/g++ -fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none -v main.cpp reports

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=offload/install/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc/configure --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --with-cuda-driver-include=/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/include --with-cuda-driver-lib=/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/lib64 --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/home/over_ng/offload/install
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.0.0 20180627 (experimental) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fopenmp' '-foffload=nvptx-none' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-pthread'
 /home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase main -version -fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none -o /tmp/cc9FAd0p.s
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 9.0.0 20180627 (experimental) (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.1.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=30 --param ggc-min-heapsize=4096
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/include
 /tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/subversion-1.9.7-f5fbcx4xhwzrq5rhhco7byj7cbx2f4fs/include
 /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../include/c++/9.0.0
 /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../include/c++/9.0.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../include/c++/9.0.0/backward
 /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /home/over_ng/offload/install/include
 /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 9.0.0 20180627 (experimental) (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.1.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=30 --param ggc-min-heapsize=4096
Compiler executable checksum: 716ed3567afb9cd0b736d2b474553211
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fopenmp' '-foffload=nvptx-none' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-pthread'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/cc2TYtU2.o /tmp/cc9FAd0p.s
GNU assembler version 2.26.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
COMPILER_PATH=/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/lib64/../lib64/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib64/../lib64/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../lib64/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/lib64/:/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/subversion-1.9.7-f5fbcx4xhwzrq5rhhco7byj7cbx2f4fs/lib/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib64/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
Reading specs from /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib64/../lib64/libgomp.spec
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fopenmp' '-foffload=nvptx-none' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-pthread'
 /home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/collect2 -plugin /home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccnGrpRF.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/crtbegin.o /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/crtoffloadbegin.o -L/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/lib64/../lib64 -L/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib64/../lib64 -L/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0 -L/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/cuda-9.0.176-m4ivnigh5kuty6u7tcnroxr5on5lot6s/lib64 -L/tools/spack/install/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/subversion-1.9.7-f5fbcx4xhwzrq5rhhco7byj7cbx2f4fs/lib -L/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib64 -L/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/../../.. /tmp/cc2TYtU2.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgomp -lgcc_s -lgcc -lpthread -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/crtoffloadend.o
/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/lto-wrapper -fresolution=/tmp/ccnGrpRF.res -flinker-output=exec -foffload-objects=/tmp/ccQDi0zV.ofldlist 
/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0//accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload @/tmp/ccJAbpMz
offload/install/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc @/tmp/ccoh8KPc
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=offload/install/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/accel/nvptx-none/lto-wrapper
Target: nvptx-none
Configured with: ../gcc/configure --target=nvptx-none --with-build-time-tools=/home/over_ng/offload/install/nvptx-none/bin --enable-as-accelerator-for=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-newlib-io-long-long --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/home/over_ng/offload/install
Thread model: single
gcc version 9.0.0 20180627 (experimental) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-m64' '-mgomp' '-v' '-fno-openacc' '-foffload-abi=lp64' '-fopenmp' '-o' '/tmp/ccNVxXFz.mkoffload'
 /home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/accel/nvptx-none/lto1 -quiet -dumpbase cc2TYtU2.o -m64 -mgomp -auxbase cc2TYtU2 -version -fno-openacc -foffload-abi=lp64 -fopenmp @/tmp/cchKIS8V -o /tmp/ccZLBhjz.s
GNU GIMPLE (GCC) version 9.0.0 20180627 (experimental) (nvptx-none)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.1.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=30 --param ggc-min-heapsize=4096
GNU GIMPLE (GCC) version 9.0.0 20180627 (experimental) (nvptx-none)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.1.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=30 --param ggc-min-heapsize=4096
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-m64' '-mgomp' '-v' '-fno-openacc' '-foffload-abi=lp64' '-fopenmp' '-o' '/tmp/ccNVxXFz.mkoffload'
 /home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/accel/nvptx-none/../../../../../../nvptx-none/bin/as -o /tmp/ccRJFdvc.o /tmp/ccZLBhjz.s
COMPILER_PATH=/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/accel/nvptx-none/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/accel/nvptx-none/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/nvptx-none/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/accel/nvptx-none/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/nvptx-none/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/accel/nvptx-none/../../../../../../nvptx-none/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/accel/nvptx-none/mgomp/:/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0/accel/nvptx-none/
Reading specs from libgomp.spec
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
mkoffload: fatal error: offload/install/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: /home/over_ng/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0//accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On the same webpage as where I found the script, somebody else reported the same problem and reverting to gcc 7.2 is apparently a solution. Since I want to include the off-loading compiler in the Spack collection, I would like to be able to use any supported version. Although I can live with gcc 8 for the time being, as 9/trunk is still experimental.

This may imply that it is a bug in gcc, in that case I would like to report it to them!

**Edit 1**: As requested, a 'sane' CPU only program that seems to work fine:

```
  #include <omp.h>
  #include <cmath>
  #include <vector>
  #include <iostream>

  int main()
  {
    const int size = 1000;
    std::vector<double> sinTable(size);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int n=0; n<size; ++n)
    {
      sinTable[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * n / size);
      std::cout << sinTable[n] << '\n';
    }

    // the table is now initialized
  }
```

This was compiled with `offload/install/bin/g++ -fopenmp -v main_cpu.cpp -o cpu`

Comment: That looks like a broken gcc setup for sure. What happens if you try and compile a sane example (no huge stack arrays please) for the CPU as an openMP target? I am going to remove the CUDA tag, I see nothing related to CUDA programming in the actual question.

Comment: @talonmies A CPU openmp program seems to work, I have added the example to the main question. Both the output is as expected (shows some race conditions with OMP_NUM_THREADS=8) and if I ldd the executable then it says it is linked to libgomp and libpthread.

Comment: Some ideas: 1. Use only absolute paths (I'm assuming `offload/install/lib64/` is `/home/over_ng/offload/install/lib64`); 2. Make sure it is on the search path. If you're positive it is on the search path but the results indicate it isn't, find something that you know for sure is on the search path (because it's compiled and linked successfully), then `cd` there and `ln -s path_to_libgomp.spec`.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the package `gcc-offload-nvptx` in the Ubuntu repository since Ubuntu 17.10.  If I compile your test code like this

```
g++ test.cpp -fopenmp
```

I get a `lto-wrapper failed` error.  This can be fixed using `-fno-stack-protector` like this

```
g++ test.cpp -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector
```

Then test code compiles and runs.  You can see that it runs on the GPU using `nvprof` like this

```
sudo nvprof ./a.out
```

---

Some additional comments. In your test code I would use

```
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
```

See [OpenMP offloading to Nvidia wrong reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49111443/2542702)

Also in your test code you should do something with `data_array` or the compiler might optimize your code away.

Ubuntu 18.04 also requires `-fno-stack-protector`.

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately I have to build to offloading compiler from scratch due to stuff out of my hands, so unfortunately I can't use the binary provided by Ubuntu. Adding -fno-stack-protector does not resolve the issue, as it goes wrong long before linking. For some reason gcc is unable to find a certain file which it put somewhere itself. In any case you're correct that my code should do something, which I have now.

Comment: @NigelOvermars you can check out the source code and build files to `gcc-offload-nvptx` in Ubuntu to see how they got it to compile.

Comment: That's an excellent idea, do you happen to know where I can find those?

Comment: I started doing this before my answer but it took too much time. But now I made a bit more progress. See https://askubuntu.com/a/28373/259597.  `sudo apt-get build-dep gcc-offload-nvptx` and `sudo apt-get source --compile gcc-offload-nvptx`. We are so spoiled nowadays (myself included) with package managers that few people know how to compile from source anymore the ways things used to be done with Linux.

Comment: @NigelOvermars https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/gcc-offload-nvptx/4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2 . I guess it's in gcc-defaults. I don't know if this is any help or a distraction.

Comment: @NigelOvermars [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49718730/2542702) got it working for Clang but I did not.